# Windows Composite device (usb audio class and custom bulk interface) via libusb?

Tags: usb, libusb

So we're looking to make a device for an internal test fixture that is a composite USB device with a standard audio class interface and a custom bulk interface.  It's primary target is Windows10.

We'd like to use libusb for the custom bulk interface  and the built in usbaudio.sys for the audio interface.

Is this possible to manage?  I've read it wasn't possible 6 years ago, but things may have progressed so I'm asking again.